# How can I extract the inference graph from TF ODI trainer without using Export and Reload?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am following a recipe to create and retrain a [TensorFlow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) graph.  The inference graph starts as a frozen graph from the [Tensorflow Object Detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md).  I retrain it for some number of steps. At that point, I want to take the graph which has been trained up to a certain point, and try it out on an image before continuing to train, without having to write out a 400MB file to disk and reload it, which seems unneccesary if the graph is already in memory.

**Note:**  I am running the training loop inside a Jupyter notebook.  The graph is saved frequently by the train function in the model.ckpt files, so I am not worried about losing the graph state. The model graph state in memory is co-equal to what is written to model.ckpt.  I am exploring the data and the training process interactively.  I should be able to switch to inference mode, do an inference, and switch back to training mode without losing the trained state of the graph. I assume that this is possible in TensorFlow, please correct me if I'm wrong.

**For comparison:** [This tutorial](https://lelon.io/blog/2018/02/08/pytorch-with-baby-steps) shows how to intersperse training and prediction interactively in PyTorch.

The broad outlines of the TensorFlow training/inference recipe are:

- **Train** an existing graph with trainer.train:

  ```
  trainer.train(create_input_dict_fn, model_fn, train_config, master,
          task, flags.num_clones, worker_replicas, flags.clone_on_cpu,
          ps_tasks, worker_job_name, is_chief, flags.train_dir,
          graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  ```
- **Export** the graph to a file with [exporter.export_inference_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/exporting_models.md):

  ```
  exporter.export_inference_graph(flags.input_type, pipeline_config,
                              flags.trained_checkpoint_prefix,
                              flags.output_directory, input_shape)
  ```
- **Reload** the graph from the file with tf.GraphDef.ParseFromString:

  ```
  detection_graph = tf.Graph()
  with detection_graph.as_default():
      od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
      with tf.gfile.GFile(checkpoint, 'rb') as fid:
          serialized_graph = fid.read()
          od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
          tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
  ```
- **Infer** an object class and location by running the graph on an input:

  ```
  with detection_graph.as_default():
      with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
          for image_np in tqdm(images):
              image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
               image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
               box = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
               score = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
               clss = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
               num_detections = 
                   detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
               (box, score, clss, num_detections) = sess.run(
                  [box, score, clss, num_detections],
                  feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
  ```

How can I skip the Export and Reload steps?  Is there a side effect of trainer.train where I can find the detection_graph that I am saving and reloading?

Comment: Requirements are not clear.

Comment: The inference graph starts as a frozen graph from the Tensorflow Object Detection model zoo.  I retrain it. During retraining and prior to exporting it again as another frozen graph, I want to use it for inference while it is still in memory.

Comment: It's actually a strange requirement. By doing so , you will have to retrain every time  before using the model, which is time and cpu consuming task...

Comment: I want to take a graph which has been trained up to a certain point, and try it out on an image before continuing to train, without having to write out a 400MB file to disk and reload it, which seems unnecesary if the graph is already in memory.  Why is that strange?

Comment: Ok..some object detection training can take days or even weeks..then not saving them on disk means the next time you run the program it will take weeks to reach that point... I understood your case...

Comment: The graph is saved frequently in the model.ckpt files.  I am exploring the data and the training process interactively.  The model graph reaches a certain state in memory which is co-equal to what is written to model.ckpt.  It should stay that way when I use the graph for an inference  I should be able to switch to inference mode, do an inference, and switch back without losing the state of the graph.  Is the question clear now?